# Linq Query ToList() Acting Up

Tags: c#, linq

```
var v = object.where(a => a.date > DateTime(2000,1,1,));
list = v.ToList();
```

Ok, so for the following code, i have break points set up on each line.  When i get to the first line, I run the code (F5) until it reaches the 2nd line.  When i step forward (F11) from the second line, it returns to the first line.  When I run the code (F5) it doesn't make it to the second line and throws an error.

Is my linq query wrong, or is something else not  working? I'm totally confuzored.

Comment: I think you need to post some actual code. The example, as-is, shouldn't compile.

Comment: Some real code would be nice. That example isn't complete and doesn't compile.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the error that is thrown?  Also, do you really mean to call 'Where' off of an object called 'object' or is that an abstraction? Also, why is there an extra comma in your DateTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to deferred execution, the lambda expression in the first line will only execute when the result is iterated in the second line.

This behavior is completely correct.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214193352/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) is a very good explanation.

Comment: This wouldn't cause the debugger to jump to the first line though.

Comment: yup. The deferred execution is implemented with a state machine using custom iterators (if I remember Eric Lippert's blog correctly). Using `yield return` wouldn't cause the debugger to jump to the line, because that would mean it would `goto` somewhere in code, completely disregarding control flow.

Comment: @Femaref: Yes, it is.  However, the debugger might still jump to the first line when stepping into the `ToList()`. I don't remember offhand.  If he set a breakpoint _inside_ the lambda, it certainly would.

Comment: I just tested it - it doesn't. The only case where that would happen would be explicitly by a `goto` or implictly by a loop.

Comment: @Femaref - Actually, yes it does. The lambda statement is a delegate, so stepping into the ToList() operation steps through external code and into the delegate method being called (which in our case is a one-liner defined in the parameter of the Where() call). You do have to step INTO the call (F11), not just OVER it (F10).

Comment: @KeithS: Even though there's no source for `ToList`?

Comment: The source of ToList is `v`, which is an `IEnumerable<T>` (concretely a `WhereIterator<T>`) produced by the `Where()` method call. The WhereIterator is an intermediate object that encapsulates the filtering behavior. When Where() is called, all the actual method does is create a WhereIterator, give it the source IEnumerable and the lambda, and return that. WhereIterator, when its GetEnumerator() method is called, will iterate through its source, and yield return each element that, when passed into the lambda, makes the lambda return true. The debug steps into the lambda when it is called here.